# Array not accepting fourth input?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with this program and I can't figure out what the problem is. It allows the user to type 3 inputs but then just gives the error!

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong (I believe it's with the 'parts' after the `.split()`, but I need the delimiter) ...

```
 public class SplittingStrings 
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Sample input(not sorted the validation yet) "Chelsea : Arsenal : 2 : 1"

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String results = sc.nextLine(); 
        int count = -1;
        String str = null;

        String[] parts = new String[100];
        parts = results.split(":");
        String home_team = parts[0];
        String away_team = parts[1];
        String home_score = parts[2];
        String away_score = parts[3];
        String[] refinedArray = new String[parts.length];

        for (int i = 0;i < 100; i++){
            results= sc.nextLine();

            for(String s : parts) {
                if(s != null) { // Skips over null values. Add "|| "".equals(s)" if you want to exclude empty strings
                    refinedArray[++count] = s; // Increments count and sets a value in the refined array
                }
            }

        if(sc.equals("stop")) {
           Arrays.stream(parts, 0, i).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        parts[i] = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Splitting a string removes the delimiter. What's the input? Did you try to run this in a debugger?

Comment: A sample input would be "Chelsea : Arsenal : 2 : 1"

Comment: Stack trace please, in the question, and an indication of which line throws the exception. Your code makes no sense whatsoever. You are reading 100 lines, but you're storing the same data from the first line into `refinedArray` regardless of what is in the current line. And a `Scanner` is never going to be equal to `"stop"`.

Comment: In other words, the code up to `refinedArray` works. Splitting the string is fine. Try to create a [mcve] with a hard coded string, then move on to a Scanner once you have it working

Comment: @Bongousse I think you're exactly correct, modulo bugs, but if the OP isn't going to clarify his question when requested what's the point?

Comment: You didn't ask me to clarify any question. I'm just trying to work out the issue with the information that you have provided. Thanks for the help nethertheless!

Comment: Rubbish. I asked you for a 'stack trace please, in the question, and an indication of which line throws the exception' nearly two hours ago, and you haven't done anything about it whatsover.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this statement: `parts[i] = str`. You change value of variable `parts` in this statement: `parts = results.split(":");` so you change size of this array (possibly lesser than 100) and in the for loop you access to an element of this array which is not existed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of 100 elements was pointless

```
String[] parts = new String[100];
```

You overwrote it with an array of only 4 (?)

```
parts = results.split(":");
```

Your loop goes up to 100, but `parts[4]` throws the exception

---

It's not really clear what `results` is supposed to be, either

Comment: I need to be able to type upto 100 lines of input ("Chelsea : Arsenal : 2 : 1") and split each of them into the four parts between ":", then store them in variables to find averages etc later. You'll have to excuse me, I'm new to java and basically stringing tutorials together